# Point wise and uniform convergence of sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Analyze the uniform convergence of the following sequences of functions:

1. $x+(1/n)$. What can we conclude about $(x+(1/n))^2$?
2. $1/(1+x)^n$ in $[0,1]$. Also, study the point wise convergence of this sequence in the same interval.

---

I have done point 1. It converges uniformly to $x$. Regarding $(x+(1/n))^2$, I concluded it doesn't converge uniformly. Is this correct?

Now, I honestly don't know how to tackle point 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At $x=0$, $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}=1$ everywhere else $f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. Thus $\|f_n-0\|_u=1$ which does not converge to $0$ ans so, $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first sequence, you are right: $\left(\left(x+\frac1n\right)^2\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise, but not uniformly, to $x^2$ (on $\Bbb R$).

The second sequence converges pointwise to$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Since $f$ is discontinuous and each of the functions from the sequence is continuous, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if I'm on the right track. I wrote $$1/(1+x)^n=1/e^{nln(1+x)}$$. So, if $x=0$ then the limit as $n$ approaches infinity is $1.$ If $0<x\leq 1$ then $ln(1+x)>0$, and the limit as $n$ approaches infinity is $0$ since the denominator $e^{nln(1+x)}$ approaches infinity. Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you want to introduce logarithms and exponentials here? If $x=0$, then $x+1=1$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{(x+1)^n}=1$. And if $x>0$, then $x+1>1$. It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x)^n=\infty$ and that therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{(x+1)^n}=0$.

Comment: You're right. It's just that as soon as I saw the nth power in the denominator I thought about using $b^n=e^{nln(b)}$